# Magento 2:How to enable google customer review survey email from google merchant center

Tags: magento2, customer, email, review, google

I am implementing the google customer review on success page. It's working fine.

But survey email  confirmation is not sending to customer after complete the order.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing dynamic values for

```
  "email": "CUSTOMER_EMAIL",
```

in integration code?

Here is the link
**https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/7106244?hl=en&ref_topic=7105160**

In FAQs for Google Customer Reviews, it says

> For customers who opt-in, **Google may email a survey invitation after
>   their purchase arrives**. Customers must complete the survey in order
>   for Google to collect their feedback as part of the Google Customer
>   Reviews program.

Have you tried after the purchase arrives?